# How to pass special char to perl script?

Tags: php, regex, perl

1) In php user enter: query like `'%key%'` or query like `'%door%'`

2) I am calling perl script as

```
ob_start();
passthru("perl -w search.pl 'query');
```

3) In the perl if i print

```
print "query: $ARGV[0]\n";
```

4) It prints as 
query like `^m'%key%'^M` or query like `^m'%door%'^M`

Any suggestions to print as user entered value.

Comment: Have you tried to print the query inside the php script, does it print correctly ? Did you realize that you're missing a double-quote? `passthru("perl -w search.pl 'query'HERE); `

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the closing **double-quote** on the `passthru` command.
I guess you need [escapeshellarg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php), i.e.:

```
$query = escapeshellarg("'%key%'");
shell_exec("perl -w search.pl '$query' ");
```

---

```
escapeshellarg()
```

> escapeshellarg() adds single quotes around a string and quotes/escapes
>   any existing single quotes allowing you to pass a string directly to a
>   shell function and having it be treated as a single safe argument.
>   This function should be used to escape individual arguments to shell
>   functions coming from user input. The shell functions include exec(),
>   system() and the backtick operator.

Comment: 1) User enter in the text box as whole text
query like '%key%' or query like '%door%'

2) in php 
$query = $_POST['textarea'];
$query_pass = escapeshellarg("'$query'");

3) sorry about the typo ( i already have  at the end")
I have passthru("perl -w search.pl query_pass");

4) when i capture perl output it looks like this print "query: $ARGV[0]\n";

'query like &#39;%key%&#39; or query like &#39;%door%&#39;'

Comment: @Newbie2Bootstrap, If there's a problem with your question, edit your question rather than posting (an equally bad) fix in the comments. Also, post the code you actually ran rather than making stuff up. Twice.